# Beginner Synth with Built-In Oscilloscope

Tags: synthesizer

I'm looking to buy a beginner-level synth that has a built in oscilloscope so that I can see the waveform as I change it (also, ideally, a built-in speaker).

As an alternative, how hard is it to hook up an external oscilloscope to a synth? Is this a better way to see this information for a beginner?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest using your ears and forgetting about the oscilloscope.

Comment: You can attach an oscilloscope to your synth output. It’s not typical for synths to have a built-in oscilloscope.

Comment: The Korg Minilogue has a built in oscilloscope display